# cross Compiling ubertooth software for ARMHF

Tags: c, makefile, cmake, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I have a software (ubertooth host ) that I need to compile on ARM, I have already compiled it on a normal Linux X64 machine and it worked. The process contains :

1. cmake ..
2. make
3. make install

Any help regarding how to cross compile for an armhf processor?

Comment: first step is [getting one](https://www.linaro.org/downloads/).. but I'm sure there are others or you could create your own.

Comment: So, you want an answer which contains what is cross-compiling using CMake, where you may obtain toolchain for BeagleBone Black, how to adjust it for your specific paths, where you may obtain CMake toolchain file... you want full **guide**. This is not how Stack Overflow works. You may start with short introduction into [cross-compiling with CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html), then google for toolchain for armhf (asking "recommendation" questions is off-topic here, [help/on-topic]), then google for ready CMake toolchain file for BeagleBone Black.

Answer (score 0):

Linux Debian Stretch has some precompiled tools for cross compiling:

```
crossbuild-essential-armhf
```

I guess that package is the one that suit your target architecture. Firstly I would try to compile with it. Probably you need to launch the build commands with the variable CROSS_COMPILE assigned properly. Eg:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
```

Other option is creating your own toolchain. Have a look to this other link https://crosstool-ng.github.io/ where you can see how to create your toolchain. This toolchain is compatible with buildroot.

If it does not work, maybe this link could be useful:

http://www.jumpnowtek.com/beaglebone/BeagleBone-Systems-with-Buildroot.html

It explain how to build buildroot for beaglebone. Buildroot is a build system used for embebed systems. It is easy to integrate new modules (libraries, binaries) to be build as part of the firmware. Once you have generated your binary for your target architecture, you only have to copy the necessary files into your target system.

If you decide to build with buildroot, have a look to the documentation:

https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html

Buildroot have support for packages based on cmake, so that, even easier if you decide for it.